# How can i Generate Json using jsonconvert.serializeobject?

Tags: c#-4.0, json.net

I need to generate `json` like follows `using Class` and Objects in `C#`.

```
{
  "title": "Joseph Sagayam",
  "url": "#person-Joseph",
  "description": "DBA",
  "actions": [
    {
      "icon": "fa-user-plus",
      "url": "#add-contact"
    },
    {
      "icon": "fa-comment-o",
      "url": "#message-contact"
    },
    {
      "icon": "fa-birthday-cake",
      "url": "#birthday"
    }
  ]
}
```

and also if i need to add blow json value

```
{
  "people": {
    "categoryName": "People",
    "results": [
      {
        "title": "Joseph Sagayam",
        "url": "#person-Joseph",
        "description": "DBA",
        "actions": [
          {
            "icon": "fa-user-plus",
            "url": "#add-contact"
          },
          {
            "icon": "fa-comment-o",
            "url": "#message-contact"
          },
          {
            "icon": "fa-birthday-cake",
            "url": "#birthday"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

what should do to this code?

Please advise me how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code:

**Class:**

```
public class Action
{
    public string icon { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class YourModelClass
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public List<Action> actions { get; set; }
}
```

**Code:**

```
var collection = new List<YourModelClass>();
dynamic collectionWrapper = new { myRoot = collection };
var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(collectionWrapper);
```

**Code edit:**

```
var collection = new List<YourModelClass>();

List<Action> newAction = new List<Action>();
newAction.Add(new Action() { icon = "fa-user-plus", url = "#add-contact" });
newAction.Add(new Action() { icon = "fa-comment-o", url = "#message-contact" });
newAction.Add(new Action() { icon = "fa-birthday-cake", url = "#birthday" });

dynamic collectionWrapper = new
{
    myRoot = new YourModelClass()
    {
        title = "Joseph Sagayam",
        url = "#person-Joseph",
        description = "DBA",
        actions = newAction.ToList()
    }
};
var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(collectionWrapper);
```

**Code update:**

```
var collection = new List<YourModelClass>();

dynamic collectionWrapper = new
{
    myRoot = new YourModelClass()
    {
        title = "Joseph Sagayam",
        url = "#person-Joseph",
        description = "DBA",
        actions = new List<Action> 
        { 
            new Action() { icon = "fa-user-plus", url = "#add-contact" },
            new Action() { icon = "fa-comment-o", url = "#message-contact" },
            new Action() { icon = "fa-birthday-cake", url = "#birthday" }
        }
    }
};
var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(collectionWrapper);
```

**Output:**

Then you will get output as per below

```
{
  "title": "Joseph Sagayam",
  "url": "#person-Joseph",
  "description": "DBA",
  "actions": [
    {
      "icon": "fa-user-plus",
      "url": "#add-contact"
    },
    {
      "icon": "fa-comment-o",
      "url": "#message-contact"
    },
    {
      "icon": "fa-birthday-cake",
      "url": "#birthday"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Last update:**

**Class:**

```
public class Action
{
    public string icon { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class Results
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public List<Action> actions { get; set; }
}

public class YourModelClass
{
    public string categoryName { get; set; }
    public List<Results> results { get; set; }
}
```

**Code:**

```
var collection = new List<YourModelClass>();

dynamic collectionWrapper = new
{
    people = new YourModelClass()
    {
        categoryName = "People",
        results = new List<Results> 
        { 
            new Results() 
            { 
                title = "Joseph Sagayam", 
                url = "#person-Joseph", 
                description = "DBA",
                actions = new List<Action> 
                {
                    new Action() { icon = "fa-user-plus", url = "#add-contact" },
                    new Action() { icon = "fa-comment-o", url = "#message-contact" },
                    new Action() { icon = "fa-birthday-cake", url = "#birthday" }
                }
            },
            new Results() 
            { 
                title = "Joseph Sagayam", 
                url = "#person-Joseph", 
                description = "DBA",
                actions = new List<Action> 
                {
                    new Action() { icon = "fa-user-plus", url = "#add-contact" },
                    new Action() { icon = "fa-comment-o", url = "#message-contact" },
                    new Action() { icon = "fa-birthday-cake", url = "#birthday" }
                }
            },
            new Results() 
            { 
                title = "Joseph Sagayam", 
                url = "#person-Joseph", 
                description = "DBA",
                actions = new List<Action> 
                {
                    new Action() { icon = "fa-user-plus", url = "#add-contact" },
                    new Action() { icon = "fa-comment-o", url = "#message-contact" },
                    new Action() { icon = "fa-birthday-cake", url = "#birthday" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(collectionWrapper);
```

**Output:**

Then you will get output as per below

```
{
  "people": {
    "categoryName": "People",
    "results": [
      {
        "title": "Joseph Sagayam",
        "url": "#person-Joseph",
        "description": "DBA",
        "actions": [
          {
            "icon": "fa-user-plus",
            "url": "#add-contact"
          },
          {
            "icon": "fa-comment-o",
            "url": "#message-contact"
          },
          {
            "icon": "fa-birthday-cake",
            "url": "#birthday"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "title": "Joseph Sagayam",
        "url": "#person-Joseph",
        "description": "DBA",
        "actions": [
          {
            "icon": "fa-user-plus",
            "url": "#add-contact"
          },
          {
            "icon": "fa-comment-o",
            "url": "#message-contact"
          },
          {
            "icon": "fa-birthday-cake",
            "url": "#birthday"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "title": "Joseph Sagayam",
        "url": "#person-Joseph",
        "description": "DBA",
        "actions": [
          {
            "icon": "fa-user-plus",
            "url": "#add-contact"
          },
          {
            "icon": "fa-comment-o",
            "url": "#message-contact"
          },
          {
            "icon": "fa-birthday-cake",
            "url": "#birthday"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please tell me how to add values?

Comment: It's really helpful then please also Up answer.

Comment: if i need to add some more like
{"people":{"categoryName": "People","results":[{
  "title": "Joseph Sagayam",
  "url": "#person-Joseph",
  "description": "DBA",
  "actions": [
    {
      "icon": "fa-user-plus",
      "url": "#add-contact"
    },
    {
      "icon": "fa-comment-o",
      "url": "#message-contact"
    },
    {
      "icon": "fa-birthday-cake",
      "url": "#birthday"
    }
  ]
}]}}

what are the changes that i have to do?

Comment: Can you please tell how to do the changes?

Comment: You mean to add those value in json output string ?

Comment: Please add this in your post

Comment: Please Advice me to do this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92952/discussion-between-boniezat-and-smoother-sillent).

Answer (score 0):

everything you need should be here
http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

```
Product product = new Product();
product.Name = "Apple";
product.Expiry = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small" };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
// {
//   "Name": "Apple",
//   "Expiry": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
//   "Sizes": [
//     "Small"
//   ]
// }
```